# autocmd check filename in vim?

Tags: vim, if-statement, autocmd

I want to write some autocmd's that check if the filename is this or that..

I've been trying:

```
autocmd VimEnter * if % is "preamble" | Explore | endif
autocmd VimEnter * if %=="preamble" | Explore | endif
autocmd VimEnter * if &filename == "preamble" | Explore | endif
```

but none of this works?

WHat should I do?

(this example is over-simplified, note that I'd also like to have an else statement).

Comment: I doubt whether VimEnter is the best event to trigger this autocmd.  VimEnter happens once when you start a Vim instance and not after that.  BufRead happens each time a buffer is opened, regardless of whether Vim was open already or not (and likewise with BufNewFile).

Comment: Yeah I'm actually using `BufNew` to make it work

Comment: Thank you all for your swift responses!

Comment: This is what I'm using to change the color scheme except if the current buffer is a MiniBufExpl bufer and it seems to be working: `autocmd BufEnter * if bufname("%") !=? '-MiniBufExplorer-' | colorscheme default | endif`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should get the current file name as `@%`. For e.g., `echo @%` will give you the filename, whereas `echo %` will not. However, for actions on the file, use `%`, e.g. `source %`.

This should probably work for what you want to do:

```
autocmd VimEnter * if @% == 'preamble' | echo 'hello' | else | echo 'world' | endif
```

Comment: Is it possible to do more than one thing in 'if' part or 'else' part? e.g. `autocmd VimEnter * if @% == 'preamble' | echo 'hello1'; echo 'hello2' | else | echo 'world1'; echo 'world2' | endif
`

Answer (score 7):

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile preamble Explore
```

Comment: Ok this works.. I would also like to have an `else` statement. Is this possible?

Comment: @romeoevs: For effect of an `else` one way is to just create another autocmd that matches everything except 'preamble'.  I think this would do it: `autocmd BufRead, BufNewFile [^\(preamble\)] function_here`  (See my separate Answer for info on what you were doing wrong and how the file-slot in autocmd works.)

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems with the examples in the original post:

1. Neither the `%` nor `&filename` will return the filename as you've used them.
   Look at the help for the `expand()` function to see how to get the filename: `:h expand()`
2. You're ignoring the slot in autocmd where a file-matching-pattern would ordinarily be specified. The third slot in the autocmd (`*` in your versions) is actually a pattern to match filenames. See `:h autocmd-patterns`. It should work okay if you want to ignore the pattern slot, but if so, you've got to fix the problem in paragraph 1 above.  E.g.,

   `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile * if expand('%') =~ "preamble" | Explore | endif`

Answer (score 3):

### Additional Info Using '@%' with autocmd

Some `autocmd` events [do not support](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#BufNew) the `@%` [named register](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers) to read the current file name. In these cases it is better to use [<afile>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%3Cafile%3E):

```
expand('<afile>')
```